# Update row value with a sub-select join

Tags: mysql, join, update, subquery

I am trying to update 1 column in all rows in a table to have an appropriate count value. Sadly, the `SELECT` query I am using won't let me join on a field in update table.

The query looks like this (trimmed for this example)

```
UPDATE people SET files_count = (
    SELECT COUNT(files.id)
    FROM messages
    JOIN threads et
        ON messages.thread_id = et.id
        AND messages.user_id = people.owner_id /* Gives error of unknown fields owner_id */
    /* other joins here */
    WHERE
        ep.person_id = people.id /* No problem with using the people table here */
);
```

As you an see in the comments in the query, I am getting an error when I try to join the `threads` table with a value from the `people` table. But, when I use the `people` table in the `WHERE` clause, all is fine. If I replace `people.owner_id` with an actual number, there is no error (but obviously this gives incorrect results).

How can I get this `JOIN` to use my parent table?

Comment: I don't really know why it behaves like that but why do you insist on using that predicate in an ON clause if it doesn't work there? Just use the WHERE clause.

Comment: @AndriyM good question, not sure why I didn't think of that. Seams to be ok that way.

Comment: @shiznatix can you add your `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statements of your tables?